# Construction of graph embeddings with non-intersecting edges

Tags: graph-algorithms, cg.comp-geom, graph-drawing

I have a bipartite graph whose genus $g$ I know. I have a genus $g$ real surface(a $g$-holed donut). I want to construct a graph embedding on the surface so that I have no intersecting edges. Has this problem been studied before?

That is given a genus $g$ bipartite graph, provide an explicit algorithm that can embed the graph in a non-intersecting manner on to a real surface with $g$ handles.

Is there any notion of equivalence of embeddings of graphs on surfaces? If so, given a genus $g$ graph, in how many non-equivalent ways can one do the embedding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The problem of finding the graph genus is NP-hard (the problem of determining whether an n-vertex graph has genus g is NP-complete). *In this case you already know the genus.*
>
> At the same time, the graph genus problem is fixed-parameter tractable, i.e., polynomial time algorithms are known to check whether a graph can be embedded into a surface of a given fixed genus as well as to find the embedding.

-[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_embedding) (who writes Graph Theory wikipedia btw? Its awesome:)

If the fact that graph is bipartite doesn't play any very special role then the problem has been studied and solved.

[A Linear Time Algorithm for Embedding Graphs in an Arbitrary Surface by Bojan Mohar](http://epubs.siam.org/sidma/resource/1/sjdmec/v12/i1/p6_s1?isAuthorized=no)

Comment: David Eppstein contributes a lot to that part of Wikipedia, which explains its awesomeness ;-)

Comment: Well, in my case, I know the genus explicitly.

Comment: I totally missed the graph embedding wiki link. It will help.

Comment: If knowing the genus of the graph made the embedding problem easy, then one could determine the genus easily by just trying all n^2 possibilities.  But determining the genus (even up to an approximation factor of n^ε) is NP-hard.  Therefore, computing a embedding of a given graph with given genus is also NP-hard.

Answer (score 6):

There is a "simpler" algorithm to check embeddability of graphs in surfaces of genus g.
See [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2008.53).

Having a bipartite graph does not help. From any graph we can obtain a bipartite version by subdividing each edge once. The embeddability of the new graph and the original one is the same.